# Facebook's React - data updating approch

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'd like to visual some data using React which structure is an simple array of objects, all necessary data is given at the input. In my case it is very similar to the example from:

http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html

However, in my case input data can change in time (adding/removing some object) which causes state changing in some nested modules. Should I render the new data over again or use Flux approach and send event to the appropriate module through Flux's dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Up to you. Just remember : the best is to have a root component holding state and let the data flow in nested components via props